# Asking people for Gamertag type IDs

Tags: support

Are we allowed to ask people for Gamertag-esque ids?

Comment: Why? [........]

Answer (score 11):

As a question on the main site? No. This is not a place to round up gamers for any sort of purpose. It's a place to get answers to practical questions, and I don't think that such a question would have any significant amount of relevance to people at large.

If you show up on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com), then you might find some users who might be willing to provide those details. But that is up to those users whether they will provide it.

Comment: Similarly, you are welcome to add that information to your profile, and to check others profiles to see if it's included. Oh, and [join the Steam Group!](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/stackexchange)